# ExpandableListView ClassCastException when using two different ViewHolders for Group

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am getting a `ClassCastException` when using two different `ViewHolders`
for my Groups an in `ExpandableListView`.

I have a separate `ViewHolder` for Group in position 0. The rest of the Groups use a different one.

This error happens after I already create the views by scrolling down and scroll back up to the Group in position 0.

I know my issue is in this line:
**`vhPropertyInfo = (ViewHolderPropertyInfo) convertView.getTag();`**

When I scroll back to Group position 0, it tries to cast `(ViewHolderPropertyInfo)` to the `convertView` that is not null, but it is actually `(ViewHolderGroup)` type. How do I resolve this?

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpandable, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (groupPosition == 0) {
        ViewHolderPropertyInfo vhPropertyInfo;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_property_info, null);

            vhPropertyInfo = new ViewHolderPropertyInfo();
            vhPropertyInfo.mTvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            vhPropertyInfo.mTvCountry = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_country);
            vhPropertyInfo.mTvCity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_city);
            vhPropertyInfo.mTvDistrict = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_district);
            vhPropertyInfo.mTvPostalCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_postal_code);
            vhPropertyInfo.mTvStreet = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_street);
            vhPropertyInfo.mTvSubStreet = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_sub_street);

            convertView.setTag(vhPropertyInfo);
        }
        else {
            vhPropertyInfo = (ViewHolderPropertyInfo) convertView.getTag();
        }

        vhPropertyInfo.mTvName.setText("House Lannister");
        vhPropertyInfo.mTvCountry.setText("Westeros");
        vhPropertyInfo.mTvCity.setText("Kings Landing");
        vhPropertyInfo.mTvDistrict.setText("West Side");
        vhPropertyInfo.mTvPostalCode.setText("12345");
        vhPropertyInfo.mTvStreet.setText("123 Kings Lane");
        vhPropertyInfo.mTvSubStreet.setText("Hut 23");

        return convertView;
    }
    else {
        ViewHolderGroup vhGroup;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_property_group, null);

            vhGroup = new ViewHolderGroup();
            vhGroup.mTvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);

            convertView.setTag(vhGroup);
        }
        else {
            vhGroup = (ViewHolderGroup) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // Group 0 is property info so have to subtract one position
        vhGroup.mTvName.setText(getGroup(groupPosition));

        return convertView;
    }
}

public final class ViewHolderGroup {
    public TextView mTvName;
}

public final class ViewHolderPropertyInfo {
    public TextView mTvName;
    public TextView mTvCountry;
    public TextView mTvCity;
    public TextView mTvDistrict;
    public TextView mTvPostalCode;
    public TextView mTvStreet;
    public TextView mTvSubStreet;
}
```

**EDIT 1: So I fixed the problem, but checking the instance of `convertView.getTag()` if it was the same type of ViewHolder type, but my solution doesn't seem very elegant. Anyone know a way to do this cleaner?**

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpandable, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (groupPosition == 0) {
        ViewHolderPropertyInfo vhPropertyInfo;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_property_info, null);

            vhPropertyInfo = new ViewHolderPropertyInfo();
            vhPropertyInfo.mTvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            vhPropertyInfo.mTvCountry = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_country);
            vhPropertyInfo.mTvCity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_city);
            vhPropertyInfo.mTvDistrict = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_district);
            vhPropertyInfo.mTvPostalCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_postal_code);
            vhPropertyInfo.mTvStreet = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_street);
            vhPropertyInfo.mTvSubStreet = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_sub_street);

            convertView.setTag(vhPropertyInfo);
        }
        else {
            if (convertView.getTag() instanceof ViewHolderPropertyInfo) {
                vhPropertyInfo = (ViewHolderPropertyInfo) convertView.getTag();
            }
            else {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_property_info, null);

                vhPropertyInfo = new ViewHolderPropertyInfo();
                vhPropertyInfo.mTvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
                vhPropertyInfo.mTvCountry = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_country);
                vhPropertyInfo.mTvCity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_city);
                vhPropertyInfo.mTvDistrict = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_district);
                vhPropertyInfo.mTvPostalCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_postal_code);
                vhPropertyInfo.mTvStreet = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_street);
                vhPropertyInfo.mTvSubStreet = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_sub_street);

                convertView.setTag(vhPropertyInfo);
            }
        }

        vhPropertyInfo.mTvName.setText("House Lannister");
        vhPropertyInfo.mTvCountry.setText("Westeros");
        vhPropertyInfo.mTvCity.setText("Kings Landing");
        vhPropertyInfo.mTvDistrict.setText("West Side");
        vhPropertyInfo.mTvPostalCode.setText("12345");
        vhPropertyInfo.mTvStreet.setText("123 Kings Lane");
        vhPropertyInfo.mTvSubStreet.setText("Hut 23");

        return convertView;
    }
    else {
        ViewHolderGroup vhGroup;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_property_group, null);

            vhGroup = new ViewHolderGroup();
            vhGroup.mTvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);

            convertView.setTag(vhGroup);
        }
        else {
            if (convertView.getTag() instanceof ViewHolderGroup) {
                vhGroup = (ViewHolderGroup) convertView.getTag();
            }
            else {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_property_group, null);

                vhGroup = new ViewHolderGroup();
                vhGroup.mTvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);

                convertView.setTag(vhGroup);
            }
        }

        // Group 0 is property info so have to subtract one position
        vhGroup.mTvName.setText(getGroup(groupPosition));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a more elegant way to do my solution. It is to do the `convertView.getTag()` checking the instanceof the ViewHolder before the check if `convertView == null`.

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpandable, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (groupPosition == 0) {
        ViewHolderPropertyInfo vhPropertyInfo;

        if (convertView != null && !(convertView.getTag() instanceof ViewHolderPropertyInfo)) {
            convertView = null;
        }

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_property_info, null);

            vhPropertyInfo = new ViewHolderPropertyInfo();
            vhPropertyInfo.mTvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            vhPropertyInfo.mTvCountry = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_country);
            vhPropertyInfo.mTvCity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_city);
            vhPropertyInfo.mTvDistrict = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_district);
            vhPropertyInfo.mTvPostalCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_postal_code);
            vhPropertyInfo.mTvStreet = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_street);
            vhPropertyInfo.mTvSubStreet = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_sub_street);

            convertView.setTag(vhPropertyInfo);
        }
        else {
            vhPropertyInfo = (ViewHolderPropertyInfo) convertView.getTag();
        }

        vhPropertyInfo.mTvName.setText("House Lannister");
        vhPropertyInfo.mTvCountry.setText("Westeros");
        vhPropertyInfo.mTvCity.setText("Kings Landing");
        vhPropertyInfo.mTvDistrict.setText("West Side");
        vhPropertyInfo.mTvPostalCode.setText("12345");
        vhPropertyInfo.mTvStreet.setText("123 Kings Lane");
        vhPropertyInfo.mTvSubStreet.setText("Hut 23");

        return convertView;
    }
    else {
        ViewHolderGroup vhGroup;

        if (convertView != null && !(convertView.getTag() instanceof ViewHolderGroup)) {
            convertView = null;
        }

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_property_group, null);

            vhGroup = new ViewHolderGroup();
            vhGroup.mTvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);

            convertView.setTag(vhGroup);
        }
        else {
            vhGroup = (ViewHolderGroup) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // Group 0 is property info so have to subtract one position
        vhGroup.mTvName.setText(getGroup(groupPosition));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```